# Plotting vectors in a coordinate system with R or python

Tags: python, r, vector, plot, coordinate-systems

I am looking for advice on plotting vectors in the cartesian plane. The task is to plot points (coordinates) and then to link them with an arrow to some source point (say 0,0). The image below should give an idea. I don't care about colours and naming vectors/points, it's just about plotting arrows in the coordinate plane. I am sure some library exists in R (or python) for plotting linear algebra vectors and operations.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

[image: vectors in a plane]
<sub>(source: [mathinsight.org](http://mathinsight.org/media/image/image/vector_2d_add.png))</sub>

Comment: "any pointers would be appreciated" *groan*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Or you can use `arrows` function in R.

```
plot(c(0,1),c(0,1))
arrows(0,0,1,1)
```

Comment: Interesting. Would it be possible to add some eye-candy to the arrow? (thickness, color, arrowhead-style, dash...)

Comment: @heltonbiker See `?arrows`. It says `col`, `lty` and `lwd` are accepted.

Comment: Also, if you want to be fancy in your labels, check out the tikzDevice package.

Answer (score 14):

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5), xlab="X", ylab="Y")
vecs <- data.frame(vname=c("a","b","a+b", "transb"), 
                   x0=c(0,0,0,2),y0=c(0,0,0,1), x1=c(2,1,3,3) ,y1=c(1,2,3,3), 
                   col=1:4)
with( vecs, mapply("arrows", x0, y0, x1,y1,col=col) )
```

It will look a bit better if you add lwd=3 to the `arrows` call. The `text` function would allow labeling and can be rotated with the 'srt' parameter.

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5), xlab="X", ylab="Y", lwd=3)
 with( vecs, mapply("arrows", x0, y0, x1,y1,col=col,lwd=3) )
 with(vecs, mapply('text', x=x1[1:3]-.1, y=y1[1:3]+.1, 
  labels=expression(list(a[1],a[2]), list(b[1],b[2]), list(a[1]+b[1],a[2]+b[2]) ) ))
```

[image]

PLease note that the `list` function inside the `expression` call is a plotmath `list`-call, different than the regular R `list` just as plotmath-`paste` is different than regular `paste`. It does not make any attempt to evaluate its argument in the parent-frame. For that one would need `bquote` or `substitute` and would probably need to use `sapply` be used to process the "interior" expressions.

Comment: I figured adding the expression vector method of labeling would be useful. Check out ?plotmath where you should learn that the plotmath `list` function is not the same as the R `list` function. That is also true of the plotmath `paste` function vis-a-vis the main `paste` function. The plotmath `list` changes commas inside expressions to literal commas as opposed to syntactic operations.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [matlib package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/matlib/versions/0.9.2).

```
library(matlib)
#setting up the plot
xlim <- c(0,6)
ylim <- c(0,6)
par(mar=c(3,3,1,1)+.1)
plot(xlim, ylim, type="n", xlab="X1", ylab="X2", asp=1)
grid()
# define some vectors
a=c(4,2)
b=c(1,3)
# plot the vectors
vectors(b, labels="b", pos.lab=4, frac.lab=.5, col="green")
vectors(a, labels="a", pos.lab=4, frac.lab=.5)
vectors(a+b, labels="a+b", pos.lab=4, frac.lab=.5, col="red")
# vector a+b starting from a is equal to b.
vectors(a+b, labels="b", pos.lab=4, frac.lab=.5, origin=a, col="green")
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

An Easy(TM) way to draw a few random magnitude 2 vectors. I first calculate the euclidean norm, else the arrow function will plot arrows from point to point creating a triangle, nice as an explanation, but not what we want. The rest is straightforward:

```
#first some vectors 
v1<-c(-3,5)
v2<-c(2,-10)
v3 <-c(0,-3)
v4 <- c(2,5)
# This one for the coordinates of the plot
ax<-c(-10,10)
# I will need the euclidean norm (two-norm) of the vectors: 
mag <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))
# I call plot to set up the "canvas"
plot(ax,ax,main="Test")
# I do the stuffz, the FIRST pair of params is the ORIGIN
arrows(0,0, mag(v1),mag(v2),lwd=4,col="red")
arrows(-2,1, mag(v3),mag(v4),lwd=4,col="blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious course of action  would be to use python's `matplotlib` package, which has a lot of plotting features.

Specifically, you'd like to reverse-engineer [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_demo.html).

Another way to get nice results, in a more artistic and less cartesian way, would be to create and render SVG using `rsvg`. I have never tried that, but SVG should have native support for arrow-heads. Also, SVG files can be edited in drawing programs like Inkscape if needed.